# Segmentation Mask RCNN and FPN

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, image-recognition

I am reading the paper https://research.fb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/maskrcnn.pdf from Facebook Research.

Mask RCNN is based on the detector Faster RCNN but with some improvement like FPN (Feature Pyramid Network), ROI align which seems more accurate than ROI pooling for example. But, I do not understand the architecture regarding the FPN and the mask in Mask RCNN. In fact, FPN permits to get feature map at different scales but looking at the image on the paper I do not understand if they used only the last feature map on the FPN or not.

[image]

So, the question is : do we use only the last feature map of the RPN and then use some conv layers for the prediction of the mask (for the segmentation) or de we also use the intermediate layers of the RPN ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCN in mask branch in mask R-CNN uses all the feature maps produced by FPN.
[Here is](https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn) one such implementation of Mask R-CNN.
Here is the snippet from code:

```
# Attach 3x3 conv to all P layers to get the final feature maps.
P2 = KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME", name="fpn_p2")(P2)
P3 = KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME", name="fpn_p3")(P3)
P4 = KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME", name="fpn_p4")(P4)
P5 = KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME", name="fpn_p5")(P5)
# P6 is used for the 5th anchor scale in RPN. Generated by
# subsampling from P5 with stride of 2.
P6 = KL.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1), strides=2, name="fpn_p6")(P5)

# Note that P6 is used in RPN, but not in the classifier heads.
rpn_feature_maps = [P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]
mrcnn_feature_maps = [P2, P3, P4, P5]  <--------------
```

[This](https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn/blob/master/model.py#L1640) is the line where the author used feature maps of FPN.